# Migration from two WebApp with use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have two WebApp.
Both refer to the same database, and the need to organize the migration of both App.
Both application setup to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.
When you start with a blank database application first comes the creation of scheme, in table __MigrationHistory create record about this, and everything is OK.
But when you start the second application should make changes to existing database tables, but the application crashes with an error - "... This table already exists"
How to solve this problem?

Example of code second app

Global.asax

```
Database.SetInitializer(new SyncContextInitializer());                
using (var context = new SyncDataContext())               
{                   
    context.Database.Initialize(force: true);

}

public class SyncContextInitializer :  MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SyncDataContext, SyncConfiguration>       
{          }

public class SyncDataContext : DataContext      
{               
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)          
    {             
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserLoginMap());             
        .......           
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);           
    }       
}

public sealed class SyncConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SyncDataContext>        
{
        private readonly bool _pendingMigrations;   

    public SyncConfiguration()            
    {              
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;                          
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;               
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(this);               
        _pendingMigrations = migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations().Any();

    }
    ......
    .....
}
```

Comment: do you need to Drop and Create the Database Always or what ?

Comment: no, I just need to update some field for already exist table, and create some new table. Classes of update and new entities added to modelBuilder

Comment: is this set up `Drop and Create a Database If Model Changes` ?

Comment: I use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion it should update existing databases to the state of the new model

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work. When you modify the model in one app, it looks at the prior migration (in code) to compare. It will try to recreate the changes made in the other app or you will get a model mismatch error.

The best solution is to maintain the models in one application. Otherwise you would have to create a migration in the other application to keep it in sync:

```
// Application 1:
add-migration MyChanges
update-database
// Application 2:
add-migration SyncMyChanges -IgnoreChanges   // Just update meta model
update-database
```

You would need to take care that there were no pending changes in App 2. See [Entity Framework Under the Hood](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood)

If the models are not shared, you may just need to create an initial migration starting point in both apps:

```
add-migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
```